# Why does this implementation of izip() not work?

Tags: python

To better understand Python's generator I'm trying to implement facilities in the `itertools` module, and get into trouble with `izip`:

```
def izip(*iterables):
    its = tuple(iter(it) for it in iterables)
    while True:
        yield tuple(next(it) for it in its)  # ERROR
        # yield tuple(map(next, its))  # OK
```

My code uses the ERROR line, and the reference implementation (given in the manual) uses the OK line, not considering other tiny differences. With this snippet:

```
for x in izip([1, 2, 3], (4, 5)):
    print x
```

My code outputs:

```
(1, 4)
(2, 5)
(3,)
()
()
...  # indefinite ()
```

, while the expected output is:

```
(1, 4)
(2, 5)
```

What's wrong with my code, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason your implementation does not work is because the `StopIteration` exception caused by one of the iterables being exhausted is thrown *inside a generator expression*.  It will only terminate the generator expression, not the enclosing generator function.

Comment: @wdscxsj: see http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t723967-generator-expressions-vs-comprehensions.html

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Thanks! Your explanation is concise and very to the point.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski: The linked page helps me understand a lot more better. Thank you!